# How can I install xcode 14.3 to Macos 12.6.8?

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to install `Xcode` version 14.3 to my Mac device, but which requires Mac OS version 13.0.

But the Mac OS maximum update is 12.6.8; no update shows on the Mac device after that.

I tried downloading the 14.3 `Xcode` manually from the `Xcode` site and installed it on the Mac device, but it is not supported on the device.

**My Mac Serial Number: C1MS937JH3QK**

Is this mac will get the 13.0 version? If no how can I install the `Xcode` version 14.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your version is already on hold, you probably will not get MacOS 13 Ventura. Due to that same reason, as you mentioned on your post, you won't be able to install Xcode 14 nor 14.3 due to it requiring macOS Ventura to work.

If you really, really, really need to use Xcode 14.3; you may consider use [OCLP](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/) to update your Mac to Ventura; although performance may be affected, and it isn't an official solution. I think it's obvious, but do this under your own responsibility and backup your files before trying this stuff.